# How can I mitigate water contact with a 2x4 screwed into concrete floor?

Tags: water, concrete, wood, basement, shelving

In my unfinished basement I am going to be installing some cantilever shelving along the walls. Basically using 2x4's attached to the joists, with a carriage bolt, and to the floor... likely using a 2x4 as a base plate. The plans are based on the 2x4's being secured to the wall. I am trying to avoid that.

The floor part is what I am trying to figure out. The basement floor grades to a drain at the corner of the house so the edge might not be perfectly flat to lay 2x4 for a base plate. I figure I can fix that with some plastic or composite shims.

My basement leaks, like most, and usually only after heavy rains. We keep nothing on the floor that we don't want damaged. However if I screw basic 2x4's into the floor, with tapcon or equivalent,  they are going to rot/mold/mildew. I *could* use PT but I am curious if there is something else I can use. (*Wife doesn't like the idea and I understand that modern PT uses CA... the brown stuff as supposed to arsenic which was the green stuff. Very much a case of happy wife happy life*).

Is there something I can put under not-PT 2x4's that will have water contact or some alternative that I can use as a base plate for simple shelving? I have not intention of attaching anything to the basement walls.

[image: CAD drawing of shelving]

<sup>Image from [woodgears.ca](https://woodgears.ca/shelves/index.html)</sup>

Comment: Why do you need these shelves attached to the floor?  I'm not all that clear on your design.  Could you add a drawing?

Comment: I agree, we need a sketch, "Cantilevered" does  not match with "attached to the joist". Why do you need a base plate for shelves? And what does the shelving have to do with a water damn on the floor?

Comment: Added images to the post.

Comment: If i understand correctly the problem you want to avoid is,  making sure the shelf standards touching the floor do not wick water or become water damaged. Some scraps of composite deck boards  under each standard would do. Trex is one brand name.

Comment: I think hanging by the joists entirety with no support from the floor would work just fine

Comment: the floor wasnt supposed to provide support it was supposed to keep the shelf still. I was trying to avoid screwing into the wall.

Comment: @Matt: once you have the shelves up, and they're loaded with a hundred pounds of stuff you'll never look at again, they'll be plenty stable.

Comment: @whatsisname But each 2x4 would only be supported by one carraige bolt in a floor joist... is that sufficient? Most of the implementations of these shelves have multiple anchor points.

Comment: @Matt, when you use a good carriage bolt, or better yet a machine screw with generously sized washers, properly preloaded, very little of the force is held up by the shear strength of the screw and is instead frictional force between the joist and 2x4, which is basically equivalent to solid wood. Unless these shelves are 100% filled with books or you have some sort of lead block collection, that will provide plenty of strength.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Mattias' article on woodgears.ca, I think you can hang the uprights from the overhead floor joists and cut them off above the floor.

The 2x4s coming down the wall provide a method to affix the shelving unit to the wall, not provide support from the floor. Some of the other contributors have "half-height" shelves pictured that only come down the wall so far.

You could probably still do it by "hanging" the uprights from the ceiling, but I don't know that it can support as much weight as installing it as designed.

[image]

Comment: Attaching them to the floor was a means to avoid screwing into the wall which erks my wife.

Comment: I am using PVC plastic trim board for various water contact situations.  Currently making a 2x4 out of two 1x4's screwed together for a well cover. My small basement door is made of a wood frame and this plastic PVC trim board, 7 years strong, no issues in damp environment.

Comment: @Matt What I'm saying is: I don't think the fact that they touch the floor or not is especially significant. If you hang the unit from the overhead joists, that will carry the weight while the vertical boards serve to hold up the individual shelves and mitigate the rotational force, etc. The amount of support from resting on the floor is negligible. It would be best to anchor the uprights to the wall, but if everything hangs from above, you should be OK as long as the weight is supported adequately.

Comment: @GregNickoloff That would mean its only anchored at the floor joist and the shelves could be moved from the bottom _slightly_. Anchoring them to the floor would stop that movement almost completly which was my goal. At this point this might be too weird and it might just be easier to put holes in the wall.

Answer (score 0):

Screw into the floor with galvanized brackets. Attach the 2x4 to the brackets with a gap. Prefably install a rubber flashing product to the bottom of the 2x4 and then use like a polyrurathane adhesive to further prevent wicking